# Kserve Sklearn Model Deployment issue

Tags: kubernetes, istio, cert-manager, kind, kubeflow-kserve

Ref - https://kserve.github.io/website/master/admin/kubernetes_deployment/

kind - kubernetes v1.25
Istio - v1.16.0
Cert Manager - v1.14.2
kserve v0.11.0 (deployed kserve without knative)

on my kind k8s cluster.

```
kubectl get pods -A
NAMESPACE            NAME                                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS         AGE
cert-manager         cert-manager-cainjector-76bbdd77f7-w4rpk          1/1     Running   4 (106m ago)     22h
cert-manager         cert-manager-cdbc489b6-mnq7d                      1/1     Running   5 (107m ago)     22h
cert-manager         cert-manager-webhook-7ffbff4575-5tlrb             1/1     Running   4 (106m ago)     22h
istio-system         istio-ingressgateway-748fb66b49-2w2wf             1/1     Running   2 (107m ago)     22h
istio-system         istiod-5d74c58fdd-x4br5                           1/1     Running   2 (107m ago)     22h
kserve               kserve-controller-manager-55d7c5685f-7s75b        2/2     Running   6 (107m ago)     22h
kserve               sklearn-iris-example-predictor-776df85f86-n6xvd   1/1     Running   118 (6m5s ago)   21h
kube-system          coredns-565d847f94-7f7nn                          1/1     Running   2 (107m ago)     22h
kube-system          coredns-565d847f94-vqvvk                          1/1     Running   2 (107m ago)     22h
kube-system          etcd-ethan-control-plane                          1/1     Running   2 (107m ago)     22h
kube-system          kindnet-jj7v7                                     1/1     Running   3 (107m ago)     22h
kube-system          kube-apiserver-ethan-control-plane                1/1     Running   2 (107m ago)     22h
kube-system          kube-controller-manager-ethan-control-plane       1/1     Running   2 (107m ago)     22h
kube-system          kube-proxy-vzbkb                                  1/1     Running   2 (107m ago)     22h
kube-system          kube-scheduler-ethan-control-plane                1/1     Running   2 (107m ago)     22h
local-path-storage   local-path-provisioner-684f458cdd-8d4qf           1/1     Running   4 (106m ago)     22h
```

```
kubectl -n kserve logs -f sklearn-iris-example-predictor-776df85f86-n6xvd     
INFO:root:Copying contents of /mnt/models to local
ERROR:root:fail to locate model file for model sklearn-iris-example under dir /mnt/models,trying loading from model repository.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/sklearnserver/sklearnserver/__main__.py", line 42, in <module>
    kserve.ModelServer(registered_models=SKLearnModelRepository(args.model_dir)).start(
  File "/sklearnserver/sklearnserver/sklearn_model_repository.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.load_models()
  File "/kserve/kserve/model_repository.py", line 37, in load_models
    for name in os.listdir(self.models_dir):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/models'
```

Similar issue ref - https://github.com/kserve/kserve/issues/3082

Anyone face a similar issue and have a solution or workaround?

Thank you

Comment: I am also facing same issue. any idea how to resolve?